# Github: Find repositories ordered by creation date

Tags: git, search, github, repository

I am trying to find the newest repositories for a language on Github, ordered by creation date.

For example, a Ruby repository created 2 days ago should show first in the results. A Ruby repository created 8 days ago should show second on the list and so on.

I have gone through the [search filter documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/search-syntax/) but they have not been much help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it. This will need to be done on the server side by GitHub and they will need to expose this info through their API.

At this moment, you only have this feature available:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-languages

---

#### Other options:

This API:

> ***List all public repositories***
>
> This provides a dump of every public repository, ***`in the order that they were created.`***
>
> **Note:** Pagination is powered exclusively by the since parameter. Use the Link header to get the URL for the next page of repositories.

Once you fetch this data you have to filter it by languages.

Comment: is this going to be done through github app or oauth app?